# Is $[a, a)$ equal to $\{a\}$ or $\varnothing$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Let us define the set $[a,b) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: a\le x <b\}$

Is $[a, a)$ equal to $\{a\}$ or $\varnothing$?

Comment: A logician would tell you that the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 11):

You can write the conditions as follows: $[a,a)=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}: a\leq x<a\right\}$. Now, since there is no real number fulfilling this condition (which, if fulfilled, implies $a<a$), the set must be empty.

Answer (score 2):

It equals the empty set, while $[a,a] = \{a\}$.

Comment: I have clarified the question. Please review your answer.

Comment: I think it remains: $[a,a) = \varnothing$, just clarifying that it's $[a,a]$ that would give you $\{a\}$.

Comment: That's fine. I just didn't want to give you a nasty surprise.

Comment: I think this is more of a philosophical question. It can be both, it is like, "glass half empty or half full" type question. @Platehead here is a pessimist...:P

Comment: Aww really? It seems to just make sense according to the definition: nothing is both $\geq a$ and $< a$ right? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can think of $[a,b) = (-\infty,b) \cap [a,\infty)$. Choose $b=a$ :D

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Classification_of_intervals):

- $[a, a) = (a, a] = (a, a) = \emptyset$ is the **empty set**.
- $[a,a] = \{a\}$ is a **degenerate set**.