# Show $\limsup A_{2^n}$ is in the tail field.

Tags: probability-theory

Given events $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$, let $\tau = \bigcap_{n\geq1} \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, ...)$ be their tail field.

Without noting that $\limsup A_{2^n} \subseteq \limsup A_{n}$, prove $\limsup A_{2^n} \in \tau$.

---

What I tried so far is base my proof on how I proved $\limsup A_{n} \in \tau$:

$\limsup A_{n} = \limsup A_{n+k-1} \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$= \bigcap_{m \geq 1} \bigcup_{n \geq m} A_{n + k - 1}$

$= (A_k \cup A_{k+1} \cup ...) \cap (A_{k+1} \cup A_{k+2} \cup ...) \cap...$

$\in \sigma(A_{k}, A_{k+1}, ...)$

$\to \limsup A_{n} \in \bigcap_{k \geq 1} \sigma(A_{k}, A_{k+1}, ...)$

$ = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \sigma(A_{n}, A_{n+1}, ...)$

---

My attempt to prove that $\limsup A_{2^n} \in \tau$:

$\limsup A_{2^n} = \limsup A_{2^{n+k-1}} \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$= \bigcap_{m \geq 1} \bigcup_{n \geq m} A_{2^{n + k - 1}}$

$= (A_{2^k} \cup A_{2^{k+1}} \cup ...) \cap (A_{2^{k+1}} \cup A_{2^{k+2}} \cup ...) \cap...$

$\in \sigma(A_{2^k}, A_{2^{k+1}}, ...)$

$\subseteq \sigma(A_{k}, A_{k+1}, ...)$ <-- Is this even right?

$\to \limsup A_{2^n} \in \bigcap_{k \geq 1} \sigma(A_{k}, A_{k+1}, ...)$

$ = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \sigma(A_{n}, A_{n+1}, ...)$

Comment: "Without noting that $\limsup A_{2^n} \subseteq \limsup A_{n}$, prove $\limsup A_{2^n} \in \tau$." This seems to indicate that you believe that $B\subseteq C$ and $C\in\tau$ imply $B\in\tau$. If indeed this is so, you might want to reconsider.

Comment: @Did Oh great! That means I was right in not using that inclusion. to prove such a statement. Thanks Did.

Comment: Do you understand why the implication is false, or are you just *admitting* it is because somebody said so?

Comment: @Did I understand intuitively. If asked to give a formal proof, it may take me some time. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16518/how-do-you-know-that-their-answers-are-correct

Comment: @Did "A logician would tell you that the answer is "yes". –  alexqwx Oct 15 '14 at 22:17" :P http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975676/is-a-a-equal-to-a-or-varnothing#comment2000583_975676

Comment: "Is this even right?" Yes. $\left\{ A_{2^{r}}\mid r=k,k+1,\dots\right\} \subseteq\left\{ A_{r}\mid r=k,k+1,\dots\right\} $
and consequently $\sigma\left(\left\{ A_{2^{r}}\mid r=k,k+1,\dots\right\} \right)\subseteq\sigma\left(\left\{ A_{r}\mid r=k,k+1,\dots\right\} \right)$.

Comment: Thanks @drhab (again) !! Btw, any idea if the proof you gave implies, or at least, has some relation to, $\limsup A_{2^n} \subseteq \limsup A_{n}$ ?

Comment: $\left\{ A_{2^{r}}\mid r=k,k+1,\dots\right\} \subseteq\left\{ A_{r}\mid r=k,k+1,\dots\right\} $
implies $\bigcup_{r\geq k}A_{2^{r}}\subseteq\bigcup_{r\geq k}A_{r}$.
This for every $k$ which leads to $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{r\geq k}A_{2^{r}}\subseteq\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{r\geq k}A_{r}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is this even right?" Yes. {A2r∣r=k,k+1,…}⊆{Ar∣r=k,k+1,…} and consequently σ({A2r∣r=k,k+1,…})⊆σ({Ar∣r=k,k+1,…}). – drhab 2 days ago

Thanks @drhab (again) !! Btw, any idea if the proof you gave implies, or at least, has some relation to, lim supA2n⊆lim supAn ? – BCLC 2 days ago
1 up voted

{A2r∣r=k,k+1,…}⊆{Ar∣r=k,k+1,…} implies ⋃r≥kA2r⊆⋃r≥kAr. This for every k which leads to ⋂∞k=1⋃r≥kA2r⊆⋂∞k=1⋃r≥kAr – drhab 2 days ago

Thanks @drhab ! – BCLC yesterday