# Is $(a,a]=\{\emptyset\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, convention

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and consider the half open interval $(a,a]$.

Is it correct to write this half open interval as $(a,a]=\{\emptyset \}$? Or $(a,a]=\{a \}$?

Comment: $(x,y]:=\{r \in \mathbf{R}: x<r\le y\}$. Hence it is empty.

Comment: It is not the set containing the empty set, it is just the empty set

Comment: $\varnothing\neq\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $[a, a)$ equal to $\{a\}$ or $\varnothing$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975676/is-a-a-equal-to-a-or-varnothing)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, $(a,a]$ has no elements.  It is empty.   There is no real number $x$ such that $a < x \le a$.  But you **do not** write that as $\{\varnothing\}$.  You write it as $\varnothing$.  See the difference?

Comment: I did not know this difference was important, so thanks. So I can clarify, $\{ \emptyset \}$ is the set containing the empty set; is this any set containing the empty set?

Comment: @möbius **THE** set containing the empty set. There "is" only one, since if two sets have the same elements, they are the same set.

Comment: @möbius No. it is the set with one element, and this element is the empty set.

Answer (score 4):

No. Because $\emptyset$, the empty set, is not a real number, i.e. it is not an element of $\mathbb R$, the set $\{\emptyset\}$ is *not* a subset of $\mathbb R$. ON the other hand, $(a,a]$ **is** a subset of $\mathbb R$, so there can be no equality.

You are close, though, since $(a,a]$ is the empty set, so $(a,a]=\emptyset=\{\}$.

Comment: I agree that $\varnothing$ is not a real number.  But (in some formulations) it may be.  Those weird model theorists start with zero as $\varnothing$ and then build up the number system from that...

Comment: Only the natural number zero is the empty set; the real number zero is either a Dedekind cut or an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences, and in either case the real number zero is not the empty set. @GEdgar

Comment: @CarlMummert In the standard model of real numbers. It is possible to construct a model of reals that has empty set as zero.

Comment: @5xum: well, we can always arbitrarily make any particular number be any particular set. But the usual two constructions of the reals - via Dedekind cuts or via equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences - do not make any real number be represented by the empty set. The real number 0 is not represented in the same way as the natural number 0.