# $(a,a]=$? Where $a \in \Bbb R$.

Tags: notation

We were taught that $[a,a]=\{a\}$ and $(a,a)=\emptyset $, For $a \in \Bbb R$.

So I wonder what will be the result in the case $(a,a]$?

Let $A=(a,a]$.

Then $a \in A$ and $a \notin A$.  This is absurd. So I guess $A$ is undefined.

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Alternately you could view it as the set of points $x$ such that $a<x\leq a$ which would also give $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122  but how to implement that idea? Since we get absurdity using it.

Comment: @VikrantDesai That was a mistake. Your idea is actually wrong. It's not true that $a \in A$ because then we'd have $a<a$. The set is just empty.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I think I understood it now.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I don't think the idea is 'wrong'. He wrote the two contradictory conditions that should be satisfied at the same time, which led to absurdity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila None of the answers given by you in the duplicate question specifically address the case of $a=b$. Please reopen this question or update your answer to the linked question to explicitly address the case of $a=b$ and $(a,b]$.

Comment: @MaxPayne please see my comment below Zachery Selk's answer. :)

Comment: @Ian: Last I recall, $a\geq b$ includes the case of $a=b$. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I got my query clarified. :) But still if I want to re-open the question can I add the tag 'proof-verification' ?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is covered by that case but it is not mentioned explicitly. You only explicitly mention $[a,b]$ for the case $a=b$.

Comment: @Ian: There is an answer to the question in the link. If someone needs clarification that $[a,b)$ or $(a,b]$ are empty when $a\geq b$ includes the case that $a=b$, then that someone doesn't deserve the attention or energy of any community member here. And indeed, it seems that the OP can make that simple inference on their own.

Comment: Searching for $(a,a]$ using SE suggest that this would actually be a better candidate for redirection: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384184/is-a-a-emptyset

Comment: @Vikrant: You could add proof-verification, which makes this a slightly different question, to which none of the three answers below is actually relevant.

Comment: @Ian: There are probably half a dozen better candidates. I picked the one I had the easiest time to find. Feel free to flag this for a moderator to re-close as a better duplicate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila okay no problem. :)

Comment: @MaxPayne The assumption $a\in A$ leads to absurdity. That does not mean that $A$ is undefined, but that the assumption $a\in A$ is wrong. Conclusion: $a\notin A$ for every $a$, or equivalently $A=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 4):

According to the (very reasonable) [definition given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints):

$$(a,a]:=\{x\in \Bbb{R}:a<x\le a\}=\emptyset$$

I think this is a fair definition.

Comment: So if $x \in A$ then $x \gt a$. Hence $x \neq a$. Also $x \le a$ means $x \lt a$ or $x = a$. But since $x \neq a$ we have $x \lt a$. Therefore we have got $x \lt a$ and $x \gt a$ which renders $A$ empty. Am I correct?

Comment: @VikrantDesai You seem to over complicate it. The set is empty simply because there is no number that is greater than $a$ and at the same time less than or equal to $a$, these two relations are mutual exclusive.

Comment: @Sil I just wanted to be bit rigorous in the proof. :D

Answer (score 1):

$A=(a,a]=?$

Let $x\in A\implies a<x\le a$ .Hence $A=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

$A =(a,a]$  is the empty set

Fred

Comment: Can you provide a reference or justification or something? Otherwise this looks very much like an opinion.

Comment: There are no reals such that $a<x \le a$